# How to parse star rating instead of string?

Tags: java, android, string

im trying to parse information from this website http://www.petwave.com/Dogs/Breeds/Airedale-Terrier.aspx.. at the end theres a table with a few attributes with star ratings. Right now i have only values with strings parsing.. is there anyway to parse ratings from a website? I would want to change these values such as Lifespan and origin into the star values ? any idea how to do this?

```
class Dog implements Serializable {
   private String name;
   private String origin;
   private String lifeSpan;
   private String sizeType;
   private String otherNames;
   private ArrayList<Detail> details;
   private String thumbnailURL;
   private String mainImageURL;
   private String url;
   private String articleText = "";
   private Breed.Name breed;

   private boolean basicDataReady = false;
   private boolean detailDataReady = false;

     Dog(String name, String sizeType, String thumbnailURL, String url,    Breed.Name breed) {
      this.name = name;
      this.sizeType = sizeType;
      this.thumbnailURL = thumbnailURL;
      this.url = url;
      this.breed = breed;
      basicDataReady = true;
  }

    Dog(String name, String origin, String lifeSpan, String url, String thumbnailURL, Breed.Name breed) {
        this.name = name;
        this.origin = origin;
        this.lifeSpan = lifeSpan;
        this.url = url;
        this.thumbnailURL = thumbnailURL;
        this.breed = breed;
        basicDataReady = true;
    }

    Dog(String name, String url, String thumbnailURL, Breed.Name breed) {
        this.name = name;
        this.url = url;
        this.thumbnailURL = thumbnailURL;
        this.breed = breed;
        basicDataReady = true;
    }

    Dog(String url, Breed.Name breed) {
        this.url = url;
        this.breed = breed;
    }

    Dog() {

    }

    public String getArticleText() {
        return articleText;
    }

    public void setArticleText(String articleText) {
        this.articleText = articleText;
    }

    public String getOrigin() {
        return origin;
    }

    public String getLifeSpan() {
        return lifeSpan;
    }

    public String getSizeType() {
        return sizeType;
    }

    public boolean isBasicDataReady() {
        return basicDataReady;
    }

    public void setBasicDataReady(boolean basicDataReady) {
        this.basicDataReady = basicDataReady;
    }

    public boolean isDetailDataReady() {
        return detailDataReady;
    }

    public void setDetailDataReady(boolean detailDataReady) {
        this.detailDataReady = detailDataReady;
    }

    public Breed.Name getBreed() {
        return breed;
    }

    public void setBreed(Breed.Name breed) {
        this.breed = breed;
    }

    public String getMainImageURL() {
        return mainImageURL;
    }

    public void setMainImageURL(String mainImageURL) {
        this.mainImageURL = mainImageURL;
    }

    public ArrayList<Detail> getDetails() {
        return details;
    }

    public void setDetails(ArrayList<Detail> details) {
        this.details = details;
    }


    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getOtherNames() {
        return otherNames;
    }

    public void setOtherNames(String otherNames) {
        this.otherNames = otherNames;
    }

    public String getThumbnailURL() {
        return thumbnailURL;
    }

    public void setThumbnailURL(String thumbnailURL) {
        this.thumbnailURL = thumbnailURL;
    }

    public String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }


    static class Detail implements Serializable {
        private final String key;
        private final String value;

        public Detail(String key, String value) {
            this.key = key;
            this.value = value;
        }

        public String getValue() {
            return value;
        }

        public String getKey() {
            return key;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: DO you wan to read data from this website? Does it have an API? Does it allow using their data in your app? You can always parse the HTML without an API, but is it really what you want to do?

Comment: yes i want to read data from the website i just want my app to read the pictures and the bottom star ratings- without an API!